# Detectar cambios en un Activity para modificar texto de botón en MainActivity

Tags: java, android, activity, botón

Tengo una app que crea una `Activity2` en segundo plano que crea una VPN, el botón que se encuentra en mi `MainActivity` inicia la segunda `Activity2` con un `Intent` y dicho botón debe cambiar su texto a "Iniciar" o "Detener" según la VPN fue creada o detenida; esto ultimo puedo hacerlo fácilmente con un contador `boolean` en el `MainActivity`, sin embargo, cuando una VPN ha sido creada en Android también inicia un mensaje en la barra de notificaciones que el usuario puede extender para ver el estado de la VPN, dicho mensaje permite también detener la VPN desde ahí.

[image: Mensaje de VPN]

Mi problema es que cuando se cierra la VPN desde aquí no hay forma de cambiar el texto del boton.

Necesito poder cambiar el texto desde `Activity2`, pero cuando intento colocar ***start*** en mi `MainActivity` como `public static`:

```
public static Button start;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Obtengo **memory leaks**, por lo que no obtengo acceso al cambio del texto del botón desde otra Activity

```
start.setText("Iniciar");
```

[image: Memory leak]

¿Existe alguna forma de lograr esto sin causar memory leaks o similares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamente no puedes tener acceso al botón desde otra Activity, pero una opción es guardar el estado en preferencias (o cualquier otra opción de almacenamiento de datos), te sugiero crear una clase que guarde el estado y en base a eso puedes saber que texto asignar:

```
class Preferencias {

private static String PREFS_KEY = "Preferencias";

    public static void setStatusButton(Context context, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("estado_boton", value);
        editor.commit();
    }


    public static boolean getStatusButton(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences Preferencias = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean User = Preferencias.getBoolean("estado_boton",false);
        return User;
    }


}
```

Si en MainActivity2 esta iniciada la sesion puedes almacenar el valor boolean `true`:

```
 Preferencias.setStatusButton(getApplicationContext(), true);
```

si esta desconectado `false`:

```
 Preferencias.setStatusButton(getApplicationContext(), false);
```

De esta forma en MainActivity puedes obtener el valor para determinar que texto mostrar:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...

    if(Preferencias.getStatusButton(getApplicationContext())){ //true
       //Conectado.
    }else{ //false
       //Desconectado. 
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Si `MainActivity` esta activa y solo regresas a ella, puedes usar el método onResume() para cambiar el texto.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
    if(Preferencias.getStatusButton(getApplicationContext())){ //true
       start.setText("Desconectar");
    }else{ //false
       start.setText("Iniciar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin embargo, el usuario puede detener la VPN con el boton **Desconectar** en el cuadro de mensaje en cualquier momento cuando se haya iniciado la VPN y necesito que el boton instanciado en MainActivity cambie su texto cuando suceda, entonces ¿como puedo detectar que que mi Activity2 (VPN) se ha detenido, desde mi MainActiity? asi cambiar desde ahi el texto.

Comment: " detener la VPN con el boton Desconectar", cuando realizas esta acción realiza :  Preferencias.setStatusButton(getApplicationContext(), false); y cuando cargues nuevamente a MainActivity puedes cambiar el texto; si MainActivity esta activa usa el  método onResume de MainActivity, realice Actualización.

Comment: oh! claro, ya veo, ahora lo entiendo, en verdad es buena idea y funciona perfecto, gracias.

Comment: @lcpr_phoenix [guardar datos en preferencias, base de datos o archivo puede ser buena idea cuando necesitas valores en cualquier modulo de tu aplicación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), saludos.